# Background of table inside cell, is not filled correctly

Tags: html, email, html-email

I'm totaly begginer in creating HTML body, but i need to create HTML body of an email, i have to put into that email message Table with some data. It is pretty simple table with 2 rows and 4 columns but, there are 3 cell that have to be splite. So i've created table (1 row 2 columns) inside that cell. And here is the problem, while filling those new cell, there "main" cell is not filled correctly, please see below.
[an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59SWp.png)
How to fill that correctly. I would be grateful for a code that fill it.
My html body:

```
<table style="text-align: center; padding: 8px; width: 600px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">Done</td>
<td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">Success</td>
<td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">Overwrited</td>
<td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">Unrecognized</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;">{1}</td>
<td>
<table style="height: 50px; width: 150px; text-align: center;" >
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="height: 50px; width: 75px; border-right:solid 1px; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;" bgcolor="#00cc00">{2}</td>
<td style="height: 50px; width: 75px; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;" bgcolor="#00cc00">{3}%</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td style="width: 150px; ">
<table style="height: 50px; width: 150px; text-align: center;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="height: 50px; width: 75px; border-right:solid 1px; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;" bgcolor="#ee4c50">{4}</td>
<td style="height: 50px; width: 75px; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;" bgcolor="#ee4c50">{5}%</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td style="width: 150px;">
<table style="height: 50px; width: 150px; text-align: center;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="height: 50px; width: 75px; border-right:solid 1px; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;" bgcolor="#99ccff">{6}</td>
<td style="height: 50px; width: 75px; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;" bgcolor="#99ccff">{7}%</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And i would like to get something like that:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYw6e.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and update your question. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you want to do, **show your code** so we can see what have you have tried so far.

Comment: Your nested tables aren't removing the default cellspacing and cellpadding that you're removing from the parent table.  Those values don't automatically descend to child elements.

Comment: This is why i have asked for the code, i have no idea what does it means, this code is generated from one of the table generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your `<table>` needs to be

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
```

this will remove the extra white padding in`<td>`

[image]

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="text-align: center; padding: 8px; width: 600px;" border="1"
  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">Done</td>
      <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">Success</td>
      <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">Overwrited</td>
      <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">Unrecognized</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;">{1}</td>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="height: 50px; width: 150px; text-align: center;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="height: 50px; width: 75px; border-right:solid 1px; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;"
                bgcolor="#00cc00">{2}</td>
              <td style="height: 50px; width: 75px; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;" bgcolor="#00cc00">{3}%</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 150px; ">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="height: 50px; width: 150px; text-align: center;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="height: 50px; width: 75px; border-right:solid 1px; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;"
                bgcolor="#ee4c50">{4}</td>
              <td style="height: 50px; width: 75px; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;" bgcolor="#ee4c50">{5}%</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 150px;">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="height: 50px; width: 150px; text-align: center;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="height: 50px; width: 75px; border-right:solid 1px; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;"
                bgcolor="#99ccff">{6}</td>
              <td style="height: 50px; width: 75px; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;" bgcolor="#99ccff">{7}%</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, this is exactly what i needed.

Comment: You are very welcome, im happy to help :) Please mark the answer as correct :)